# Root partition oddly full

Tags: partitioning, root, disk

The root partition of my 12.10 Kubuntu distro is full and I don't really understand why, since fileflight shows that 72% of the disk space usage of my root partition is being used by the `~` folder,  which should be in a different partition.

I have a Kubuntu distro 12.10 , installed along with Windows 7 dual boot.

The partitions of my 1 terabyte hard drive are:

- 720GB to my windows partition
- 200MB boot partition
- 200GB extended partition:

  1. 177GB `/home` - 13gb used
  2. 14GB `/` - 12,9gb used
  3. 8GB swap

It seems like the disk space is being shared and everything I add/put on my home partition is being reflected on my root partition.

Is this normal?

sudo mount output:

```
/dev/sda6 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
/dev/sda5 on /home type ext4 (rw)
```

df output:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on  
/dev/sda6       14156280 13172704    264472  99% /  
udev             1984828       12   1984816   1% /dev  
tmpfs             799100      960    798140   1% /run  
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock  
none             1997744      224   1997520   1% /run/shm  
none              102400        8    102392   1% /run/user  
/dev/sda5      183681828 14293548 160057764   9% /home
```

Solved it.

The problem was that virtualbox installed my Windows Server 2012 ¿image? in the root partition, inside the root folder. Firelight was misleading me.

Comment: What's the output of `df -h` and `du -xhd 1 /` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The root partition of my 12.10 Kubuntu distro is full and I don't really understand why, since fileflight shows that 72% of the disk space usage of my root partition is being used by the "home/"My account name"" folder, wich should be in a different partition.

It sounds like either your `/home` may not actually be a different partition, or fileflight (which I'm not familiar with) is misleading you a bit and including the contents of `/home` when it shows the contents of `/`.

At any time you can see your mount points with `sudo mount`.  There should be one that says `on /home` - that will tell you which partition is mounted where.  At any rate, it may help us to figure out what the problem may be.

You can also find out what directories in particular are taking up a lot of space with the `du` tool.  For instance, you could go into `/` and run `sudo du --max-depth=2` to get a summary of where the big files are.

Comment: I edited my original post with the output

Comment: Thanks for that.  What about the `du` output?  Maybe fileflight (which I'm not familiar with) is misleading?  For example, maybe it it's traversing multiple mounts/filesystems.  I've edited my answer a bit to add info on using du.

Comment: Solved it. Thanks man, you were pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will exactly work, but you said that you still run windows. Maybe try running EaseUS partitioner in Windows. Only problem is, it's a tiny bit risky to edit partitions with. Good luck!

Comment: But the problem is that all the files that I put or delete from my /home partition seems to affect the root aswell. Shouldn't be independant partitions?. Why would I want to have different partitions if the disk space is shared?